# Autodesk forge transform extension turn on / off X, Y, Z axes

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

i'm using the [transform extension](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions/blob/master/public/extensions/TransformationExtension/contents/main.js). Sometimes I want the x, y and z axes to be closed. For example, in [this](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=tran#misc_controls_transform) three.js example, pressing the x, y or z keys can be opened and closed via a feature such as [.showX](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_controls_transform.html#L144). When I try this in the forge extension, there is no such feature. What can I do about it.
I am simply writing such code [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions/blob/master/public/extensions/TransformationExtension/contents/main.js#L275). Console log is written, but the axis are still visible.

```
 document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
            if (event.key === "x") {
                console.log("X press");
                _transformControlTx.showX = !_transformControlTx.showX;
            }
            if (event.key === "y") {
                console.log("Y press");
                _transformControlTx.showY = !_transformControlTx.showY;
            }
            if (event.key === "z") {
                console.log("Z press");
                _transformControlTx.showZ = !_transformControlTx.showZ;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been discussed on Forge accelerator last week. The discussion is copied here for reference:

**Xiaodong:**
The transform tool is based on THREE.TransformControls. In the new version of TRHEE.js, it looks it supports handling visibility of the axis, but since Forge Viewer is packaged from old version of three.js, I am afraid it does not support yet. copied my colleagues @Varun Patil - Forge Team, @Petr Broz (Forge Team) (because of time diff, it may take some time they comment).

it seems one more workaround from community: [Three.js Transform Controls - How to show only two arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47990824/three-js-transform-controls-how-to-show-only-two-arrows)

**Eason:**
I compared two TransformControls between three.js example and Forge viewer’s. Unfortunately, they are totally different one. Forge Viewer’s TransformControls is based on three.js r71, so it doesn’t have the direct showing/hiding axises support. You need to do that as the Stack Overflow thread above does.

**Petr:**
I’m afraid that the transform tool from three.js might be manipulating the scene graph during runtime, adding and removing 3D objects as needed… that would explain why your modifications don’t seem to stick. in general, if you need to modify some component of three.js that is not extensible, instead of fighting with the implementation I’d probably suggest building your own… if all you need is a movement in X or Y, you could just have a 3D object with two thin cylinders, red and green, and handle their mouseover, mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup events