# Three JS disable axis of TranformControls

Tags: typescript, three.js

TranformControls in scale mode have 9 'objects': arrows for X, Y, Z axes, special rectangles for XY, YZ, XZ plane and 3 white cubes in the end of each arrow. These white cubes change the scale of object along all axes. Is it posible to show only white cubes and hide all other objects of TransformControl?

I found some [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47990824/three-js-transform-controls-how-to-show-only-two-arrows) that suggests trying this to disable the X axis:

```
this.transformControl.children[0].children[0].children[0].visible = false;
this.transformControl.children[0].children[0].children[1].visible = false;
```

However, this code doesn't seem to have any effect. The way I'm working with the object:

```
 this.httpClient.get('assets/quality.obj', {responseType: 'text'})
            .subscribe(data => {
                const loader = new OBJLoader();
                const qualityObj = loader.parse(data);
                // setting up material and postion here
                //this.transformControl.children[0].children[0].children[0].visible = false;
                //this.transformControl.children[0].children[0].children[1].visible = false;
                this.transformControl.setMode("scale");
                //this.transformControl.children[0].children[0].children[0].visible = false;
                //this.transformControl.children[0].children[0].children[1].visible = false;
                this.transformControl.attach(qualityObj);
                //this.transformControl.children[0].children[0].children[0].visible = false;
                //this.transformControl.children[0].children[0].children[1].visible = false;
                this.scene.add(qualityObj);
                //this.transformControl.children[0].children[0].children[0].visible = false;
                //this.transformControl.children[0].children[0].children[1].visible = false;
            });
```